# how to use package of python to create link

Tags: python, linux, macos

In windows, pywin32 package can create a shortcut link to a directory or a file. But how can I do this in MAC OS with python? Which package or command should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os

link_name = 'linkname'
file_name = './filename'

# hard link
cmd = 'ln ' + file_name + ' ' + link_name
os.popen(cmd)

# soft link
cmd = 'ln -s ' + file_name + ' ' + link_name
os.popen(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not *quite* the same, but [`os.symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.symlink).